# How to use selenium to iterate and click every link text that their text is the same?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I tried to craw this website by using selenium:

https://www.rtings.com/headphones/reviews/best/by-price/under-200

At the bottom of this page, there are a scrollable table and there are a linked text `See Review`, I tried to use selenium to click the `See Review`,

I used `browser.find_element_by_link_text('See Review').click()` and it successfully click the first linked text.

When I try to iterate through every `See Review`, I use `browser.back()` and click `See Review` again but it always click the first linked text

How to iterate through the link text?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that should work.

```
# wait for the page loading
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.LINK_TEXT,'See Review')))

# get number of See Review links
see_review_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_link_text('See Review'))

for review in range(see_review_count-1):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'See Review')))
    linkEle = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('See Review')[review]
    linkEle.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    linkEle.click()
    # do your logic here
    # XXXXXX
    # click on back
    driver.back()
```